# Sufficiency of $|X|$ when $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ without using Factorization theorem

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, inference, sufficient-statistics, factorisation-theorem

**Question:**

> Given, $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. By means of conditional approach show that $|X|$ is a sufficient estimator for $\sigma^2$.

**My Attempt:**

This problem is very easy if we use *Fisher–Neyman Factorisation theorem*. But in this problem we have to use the basic definition of *Sufficient Statistics*, i.e,

A statistic $t = T(X)$ is sufficient for underlying parameter $\theta$ precisely if the conditional probability distribution of the data $X$, given the statistic $t = T(X)$, does not depend on the parameter $θ$.

$X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, here parameter, $\theta=\sigma^2$.
So we have to show that $P_{\sigma^2}(X\le\ x\mid T(X)\le\ t)$ is independent of $\sigma^2$.

For $x\in\ (-t,t]$,

\begin{align}
P_{\sigma^2}(X\le\ x \mid T(X)\le\ t)&= \frac{P_{\sigma^2}(X\le\ x,T(X)\le\ t)}{P_{\sigma^2}(T(X)\le\ t)}
\\&=\frac{P_{\sigma^2}(X\le\ x,|X|\le\ t)}{P_{\sigma^2}(|X|\le\ t)}
\\&=\frac{P_{\sigma^2}(-t\le\ X\le\ x)}{P_{\sigma^2}(-t\le\ X\le\ t)}
\end{align}

But how to show that this expression is free of $\sigma^2$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you have $T(X) \leq t$, not $T(X) = t$, in your conditional expression.  The "given" part of the definition, however, is "given $T(X) = t$".

Comment: Avoid [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3160967/321264). Choose where you want to ask.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry about that. I was totally unaware of the fact that there exists another site only for statistics purpose i.e Cross Validated. I assure you that I will not commit this mistake next time.